# First defined Here c++ error by adding one file

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a very interesting error that I am having a hard time root out. Maybe someone here can shed some light.

So I Have 3 files, one header file and 2 source files. My header file contains my class definition. One of my source files contains all of the class implementation. I decided to create a new file in order to help organize my source a little bit more and give it some structure.

When I have all of my code in the one source file, it compiles fine.

However, when I create a new source file and add in the include statement:

```
#include "UI/OmniFEM.h"
```

I receive the following error

> ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o:(.rodata+0x30): multiple definition of `OmniFEMMainFrame::sm_eventTable'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:(.rodata+0x30): first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`OmniFEMMainFrame::GetEventHashTable() const':
>   /home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: multiple definition of `OmniFEMMainFrame::GetEventHashTable() const'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`wxEventTableEntry':
>   /usr/include/wx-3.0-unofficial/wx/event.h:3201: multiple definition of `OmniFEMMainFrame::sm_eventHashTable'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/atomicity.h:49: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`wxWindowBase::CanBeFocused() const':
>   /home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: multiple definition of `OmniFEMMainFrame::sm_eventTableEntries'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`wxMDIParentFrameBase::OnCreateClient()':
>   /home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:76: multiple definition of `wxCreateApp()'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:76: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`main':
>   /home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:76: multiple definition of `main'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:76: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`wxGetApp()':
>   /home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:76: multiple definition of `wxGetApp()'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:76: first defined here
>   ./Debug/UI_test.cpp.o: In function`wxMDIParentFrameBase::ArrangeIcons()':
>   /home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: multiple definition of `wxTheAppInitializer'
>   ./Debug/UI_mainOmniFEMUI.cpp.o:/home/philm/GitHub/Omni-FEM/./Include/UI/OmniFEM.h:57: first defined here

The point is is this, I receive multiple first defined here errors. I am not sure why because I only have one line of code in the source file which is the include statement for the header file. When I remove this statement, the code compiles just fine again.

I did not find it necessary to post the code because again, the source file is empty save for the single line for the include statement. However, if it helps the community, please let me know and I will post the source for the class implementation.

For those curious, I am using ubuntu 14.04 and the codelite IDE.

EDIT:

Per a user request, here is the code for my other source file:

```
#include "UI/OmniFEM.h"


bool OmniFEMApp::OnInit()
{
   OmniFEMMainFrame *frame = new OmniFEMMainFrame("Omni-FEM", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
   frame->Show( true );
   return true; 
}


OmniFEMMainFrame::OmniFEMMainFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    /* Initilize variables */
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    wxMenu *menuEdit = new wxMenu;
    wxMenu *menuView = new wxMenu;
    wxMenu *menuMesh = new wxMenu;
    wxMenu *menuProblem = new wxMenu;
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;

    /* This creates the main menu Bar at the top */
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuEdit, "&Edit");
    menuBar->Append(menuView, "&View");
    menuBar->Append(menuMesh, "&Mesh");
    menuBar->Append(menuProblem, "&Problem");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");


    /* Creating the menu listing of File menu */
    menuFile->Append(ID_New, "&New\tCtrl-N");
    menuFile->Append(ID_Save, "&Save\tCtrl-S");
    menuFile->Append(ID_SaveAs, "&Save As");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);

    /* Creating the menu listinging of the Edit Menu */
    menuEdit->Append(ID_Preferences, "&Preferences\tCtrl-P");

    /* Creates the menu listing of the help menu */
    menuHelp->Append(ID_Manual, "View Manual");
    menuHelp->AppendSeparator();
    menuHelp->Append(ID_License, "License");
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);

    /* Create and display the menu bar */
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    CreateStatusBar();

    SetStatusText("Menu test for Omni-FEM");
}



void OmniFEMMainFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    Close(true);
}



void OmniFEMMainFrame::onNewFile(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Created New File", "New File Creation", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}



void OmniFEMMainFrame::OnSave(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Work saved", "Save", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}



void OmniFEMMainFrame::onSaveAs(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Work saved in location", "Saved As", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}



void OmniFEMMainFrame::onPreferences(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Preferences are located here", "Preferences", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}


void OmniFEMMainFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a test", "New File", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}

void OmniFEMMainFrame::onManual(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is the manual", "Manual", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}

void OmniFEMMainFrame::onLicense(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is the license", "License", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
```

And here is the code for the header file:

```
#ifndef OMNIFEM_H_
#define OMNIFEM_H_

#include <wx/wx.h>

class OmniFEMApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit();
};



class OmniFEMMainFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    OmniFEMMainFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size);
private:
    /* This section is for the File menu */
    void onNewFile(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnSave(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void onSaveAs(wxCommandEvent &event);

    /* This section is for the Edit menu */
    void onPreferences(wxCommandEvent &event);

    /* This section is for the Help menu */
    void onManual(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void onLicense(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event);

    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};



enum
{
    ID_New = 1,
    ID_Save = 2,
    ID_SaveAs = 3,
    ID_Preferences = 4,
    ID_Manual = 5,
    ID_License = 6
};



wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(OmniFEMMainFrame, wxFrame)
    /* This section is for teh file menu */
    EVT_MENU(ID_New,   OmniFEMMainFrame::onNewFile)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Save, OmniFEMMainFrame::OnSave)
    EVT_MENU(ID_SaveAs, OmniFEMMainFrame::onSaveAs)

    /* This section is for the view menu */
    EVT_MENU(ID_Preferences, OmniFEMMainFrame::onPreferences)

    /* This section is for the Help menu */
    EVT_MENU(ID_Manual, OmniFEMMainFrame::onManual)
    EVT_MENU(ID_License, OmniFEMMainFrame::onLicense)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, OmniFEMMainFrame::OnAbout)

    /* Everything Else */
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT,  OmniFEMMainFrame::OnExit)

wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(OmniFEMApp);


#endif /* OMNIFEM_H_ */
```

Comment: It only takes one include statement to include a massive amount of code, including the code that was already compiled in another translation unit, resulting in duplicates at link time. Just because you only have one include statement, doesn't mean that you can't get link errors.

Comment: So then, how would I include the header file into my source file without getting the linker errors? It seems that what you are saying is that the compiler is compiling the header file twice

Comment: The problem is not with including the header file. The problem is in what's in the header file. If there's code in the header file, it'll get compiled in whatever translation unit includes it. There is no difference, whatsoever, between a header file and a .cpp file. If you have "int foo(){}" and "int foo(){}" in two .cpp files, you compile, and link them, you'll get a duplicate error. if you have that in a header file, and include that header file from both .cpp files, it's the same thing. Remove all code from your header files, and put the code in only one .cpp file.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the code is somehow being compiled twice, but I do not see what it is that is in my code to cause this. I have the appropriate header guards. Yet somehow the code is being compiled twice on build

Comment: The only logical explanation, given the additional information you posted, is that all the macros referenced in the header file: wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE, wxBEGIN_END_TABLE, and wxIMPLEMENT_APP -- they all expand out to robo-generated code, the same code that gets compiled in every translation unit that includes the header file.

Comment: Thanks sam, is there anything that I can do in order to correct the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys, after asking the question on another forum, the problem has been solved.

Basically, the code

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(OmniFEMMainFrame, wxFrame)
    /* This section is for teh file menu */
    EVT_MENU(ID_New,   OmniFEMMainFrame::onNewFile)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Save, OmniFEMMainFrame::OnSave)
    EVT_MENU(ID_SaveAs, OmniFEMMainFrame::onSaveAs)

    /* This section is for the view menu */
    EVT_MENU(ID_Preferences, OmniFEMMainFrame::onPreferences)

    /* This section is for the Help menu */
    EVT_MENU(ID_Manual, OmniFEMMainFrame::onManual)
    EVT_MENU(ID_License, OmniFEMMainFrame::onLicense)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, OmniFEMMainFrame::OnAbout)

    /* Everything Else */
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT,  OmniFEMMainFrame::OnExit)

wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(OmniFEMApp);
```

Needs to be placed in the .cpp file and not the header file. This fixed the issue